# How to capture the screen of a window that contains transparency?

Tags: c++, windows, gdi+

Trying to find a way that **also** works when the window is covered by another.

I tried `PrintWindow` but it doesn't store the transparency information in the `hdc`.

I also tried `BitBlt`, but the image saved doesn't contains the window transparency, and I'm not sure how to capture it when its covered by another windows.

```
int CaptureAnImage(HWND hWnd)
{
    HDC hdcScreen;
    HDC hdcWindow;
    HDC hdcMemDC = NULL;
    HBITMAP hbmScreen = NULL;
    BITMAP bmpScreen;
    DWORD dwBytesWritten = 0;
    DWORD dwSizeofDIB = 0;
    HANDLE hFile = NULL;
    char* lpbitmap = NULL;
    HANDLE hDIB = NULL;
    DWORD dwBmpSize = 0;

    // Retrieve the handle to a display device context for the client 
    // area of the window. 
    hdcScreen = GetDC(hWnd); // GetDC(NULL);
    hdcWindow = GetDC(hWnd);

    // Create a compatible DC, which is used in a BitBlt from the window DC.
    hdcMemDC = CreateCompatibleDC(hdcWindow);

    if (!hdcMemDC)
    {
        MessageBox(hWnd, L"CreateCompatibleDC has failed", L"Failed", MB_OK);
        goto done;
    }

    // Get the client area for size calculation.
    RECT rcClient;
    GetClientRect(hWnd, &rcClient);

    // This is the best stretch mode.
    SetStretchBltMode(hdcWindow, HALFTONE);

    // The source DC is the entire screen, and the destination DC is the current window (HWND).
    if (!StretchBlt(hdcWindow,
        0, 0,
        rcClient.right, rcClient.bottom,
        hdcScreen,
        0, 0,
        rcClient.right, //GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXSCREEN),
        rcClient.bottom, //GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYSCREEN),
        SRCCOPY | CAPTUREBLT))
    {
        MessageBox(hWnd, L"StretchBlt has failed", L"Failed", MB_OK);
        goto done;
    }

    // Create a compatible bitmap from the Window DC.
    hbmScreen = CreateCompatibleBitmap(hdcWindow, rcClient.right - rcClient.left, rcClient.bottom - rcClient.top);

    if (!hbmScreen)
    {
        MessageBox(hWnd, L"CreateCompatibleBitmap Failed", L"Failed", MB_OK);
        goto done;
    }

    // Select the compatible bitmap into the compatible memory DC.
    SelectObject(hdcMemDC, hbmScreen);

    // Bit block transfer into our compatible memory DC.
    if (!BitBlt(hdcMemDC,
        0, 0,
        rcClient.right - rcClient.left, rcClient.bottom - rcClient.top,
        hdcWindow,
        0, 0,
        SRCCOPY | CAPTUREBLT))
    {
        MessageBox(hWnd, L"BitBlt has failed", L"Failed", MB_OK);
        goto done;
    }

    // Get the BITMAP from the HBITMAP.
    GetObject(hbmScreen, sizeof(BITMAP), &bmpScreen);

    BITMAPFILEHEADER   bmfHeader;
    BITMAPINFOHEADER   bi;

    bi.biSize = sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER);
    bi.biWidth = bmpScreen.bmWidth;
    bi.biHeight = bmpScreen.bmHeight;
    bi.biPlanes = 1;
    bi.biBitCount = 32;
    bi.biCompression = BI_RGB;
    bi.biSizeImage = 0;
    bi.biXPelsPerMeter = 0;
    bi.biYPelsPerMeter = 0;
    bi.biClrUsed = 0;
    bi.biClrImportant = 0;

    dwBmpSize = ((bmpScreen.bmWidth * bi.biBitCount + 31) / 32) * 4 * bmpScreen.bmHeight;

    // Starting with 32-bit Windows, GlobalAlloc and LocalAlloc are implemented as wrapper functions that 
    // call HeapAlloc using a handle to the process's default heap. Therefore, GlobalAlloc and LocalAlloc 
    // have greater overhead than HeapAlloc.
    hDIB = GlobalAlloc(GHND, dwBmpSize);
    lpbitmap = (char*)GlobalLock(hDIB);

    // Gets the "bits" from the bitmap, and copies them into a buffer 
    // that's pointed to by lpbitmap.
    GetDIBits(hdcWindow, hbmScreen, 0,
        (UINT)bmpScreen.bmHeight,
        lpbitmap,
        (BITMAPINFO*)&bi, DIB_RGB_COLORS);

    // A file is created, this is where we will save the screen capture.
    hFile = CreateFile(L"captureqwsx.png",
        GENERIC_WRITE,
        0,
        NULL,
        CREATE_ALWAYS,
        FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL);

    // Add the size of the headers to the size of the bitmap to get the total file size.
    dwSizeofDIB = dwBmpSize + sizeof(BITMAPFILEHEADER) + sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER);

    // Offset to where the actual bitmap bits start.
    bmfHeader.bfOffBits = (DWORD)sizeof(BITMAPFILEHEADER) + (DWORD)sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER);

    // Size of the file.
    bmfHeader.bfSize = dwSizeofDIB;

    // bfType must always be BM for Bitmaps.
    bmfHeader.bfType = 0x4D42; // BM.

    WriteFile(hFile, (LPSTR)&bmfHeader, sizeof(BITMAPFILEHEADER), &dwBytesWritten, NULL);
    WriteFile(hFile, (LPSTR)&bi, sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER), &dwBytesWritten, NULL);
    WriteFile(hFile, (LPSTR)lpbitmap, dwBmpSize, &dwBytesWritten, NULL);

    // Unlock and Free the DIB from the heap.
    GlobalUnlock(hDIB);
    GlobalFree(hDIB);

    // Close the handle for the file that was created.
    CloseHandle(hFile);

    // Clean up.
done:
    DeleteObject(hbmScreen);
    DeleteObject(hdcMemDC);
    ReleaseDC(NULL, hdcScreen);
    ReleaseDC(hWnd, hdcWindow);

    return 0;
}



int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{

    HWND hWnd = FindWindow(NULL, L"Untitled - Notepad");


    DWORD exstyle = GetWindowLong(hWnd, GWL_EXSTYLE);
    SetWindowLong(hWnd, GWL_EXSTYLE, exstyle | WS_EX_LAYERED);
    SetLayeredWindowAttributes(hWnd, 0, 100, LWA_ALPHA);

    CaptureAnImage(hWnd);
}
```

Comment: Does these links help? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wingdi/nf-wingdi-transparentblt https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wingdi/nf-wingdi-alphablend. In the first link there is a line in the Remark section *"When the SetStretchBltMode function is used, the iStretchMode modes of BLACKONWHITE and WHITEONBLACK are converted to COLORONCOLOR for the TransparentBlt function."*

Comment: @kiner_shah dont think so, `TransparentBlt ` all it does is make a single color transparent, as in Windows 98.

Comment: What I was thinking is that if any of the functions I mentioned would - read the RGBA value and then apply (alpha blend operation) A (alpha channel) to each R, G and B and then store the resultant R', G' and B' to a bitmap. Did you check AlphaBlend function?